# Is there a 32-bit ARM version of Windows that can run x86 applications?

Tags: windows, arm, x86, windows-rt

Windows 10 can run on **64-bit** ARM CPUs. The operating system's `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` environment variable shows `ARM64` - meaning that its a 64-bit operating system running on ARM. This operating system can run 64-bit ARM applications, plus it can run 32-bit ARM applications (`%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%`=`ARM`) and 32-bit IA-32/x86 applications (`%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%`=`x86`) through the Windows on Windows (WOW) compatibility/emulation layer.

Windows also released a few **32-bit** ARM operating systems. The recent ones I know of are:

- Windows RT (Windows 8 / Windows 8.1 on ARM)
- Windows 10 Mobile
- Windows 10 IoT Core
- (there may be others; if I am missing any, please drop a comment!)

My question is: **can any of the 32-bit ARM operating systems run Intel IA-32/x86 applications through the WOW compatibility/emulation layer? If so, which?** Or do all 32-bit ARM Windows operating systems lack a WOW subsystem for these x86 applications?

(I know that Windows RT does not support any x86 applications, but I am not sure about the others. I'm also not sure that my bulleted list is complete)

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66004902/is-there-a-programmatic-way-to-determine-which-application-processor-architectur

Comment: To scope the question and exclude operating systems like Windows CE, I'm only really interested in versions of Windows capable of running PowerShell or _maybe_ VBScript. Thanks!

Comment: The Surface Pro X runs Windows on an ARM processor and has 32-bit x86 emulation. 64-bit emulation is on the way. I doubt this is supported in 32-bit builds, IoT, RT, or mobile editions of Windows, you probably need to find an image for the full version of Windows 10 for your device.

Comment: More information about Windows-on-Arm x86 emulation https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2020/12/10/introducing-x64-emulation-in-preview-for-windows-10-on-arm-pcs-to-the-windows-insider-program/

Comment: Windows on ARM is only sold on compatible devices with specific ARM processors.

Comment: @Mokubai, the Surface Pro X runs Windows 10 (ARM64). I have a similar device and am very familiar with Windows 10 on ARM64. I've also read the blog that you linked and am aware that Microsoft is adding x64 emulation support to ARM64 Windows 10, but that doesn't get me any closer to answering the question.

Comment: @FrankLesniak hence why I only posted a couple of comments, reading your question it was not 100% clear that you knew that x86-32 emulation was available on ARM64. I suspect from the GPU driver support required by x86-32 on ARM64 (from that blog page) that it uses the GPU (or features provided by modern hardware through it) to do fast JIT compiling and hence requires a minimum hardware baseline which may well put it outside of being possible on older ARM32 systems. Repurposing old hardware that does not support this use case may not be workable.

Comment: Thanks, I suspect the same. Hopefully someone that _knows for sure_ (e.g., someone at Microsoft :-D) can chime in. I'm firing up Windows 10 IoT Core on Raspberry Pi to confirm that it does not support x86.

Comment: Related question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66004902/is-there-a-programmatic-way-to-determine-which-application-processor-architectur